# Oracle regexp cant seem to get it right

Tags: regex, oracle11g, oracle12c

I have some values like

```
CR-123456
ECR-12345
BCY-499494
134-ABC
ECW-ECR1233
CR-123344
```

I want to match all lines which do not start with ECR and the regex for doing so is ^((?!ECR)\w+) which seems to do what I want. 
But then I want to replace the matched values which do not begin with ECR and replace them with ECR and i am blanked because the following doesn't seem to work

> select regexp_replace('CR-123344','^((?!ECR)\w+)','ECR')   from dual

Any ideas where i have gone wrong ?
I want the result to be

```
ECR-123456
ECR-12345
ECR-499494
ECR-ABC
ECR-ECR1233
ECR-123344
```

Comment: Can you please post the needed result for your sample data?

Comment: I want the results to be prefixed with ECR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use substring and instr to replace everything before the dash, but here is your answer using regexp:

```
 WITH aset
     AS (SELECT 'CR-123456' a
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'BCY-12345' a
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'ECR-499494' a
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '134-ABC' a
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'ECW-ECR1233' a
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'CR-123344'
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT a, regexp_replace(a, '^([^-]*)','ECR') b
  FROM aset;
```

> Results in

```
    A,B
CR-123456,ECR-123456
BCY-12345,ECR-12345
ECR-499494,ECR-499494
134-ABC,ECR-ABC
ECW-ECR1233,ECR-ECR1233
CR-123344,ECR-123344
```

Comment: Hi Brian why would you use substring and instr isn't the regex answer that you posted more elegant?

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen did a great job of answering your question in his response. In addition, adding the "where" clause that Tim did cuts down on the number of records updated, which is always a good idea. Regular expressions can be very difficult to understand. Maybe its because I have used 'substr' and 'instr' a lot, but I find that method easier to understand than the regexp method.

Answer (score 1):

You don't absolutely need to use regex here, you can just use Oracle's base string functions.

```
SELECT
    'ECR-' || SUBSTR(col,
                     INSTR(col, '-') + 1,
                     LENGTH(col) - INSTR(col, '-')) AS new_col
FROM yourTable
WHERE col NOT LIKE 'ECR-%'
```

The advantage of this approach is that it might run faster than a regex.  The disadvantage is that the code is a bit less tidy, but if you understand how it works then this is the most important thing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are replacing characters before the '-' with ECR. Do you need to check if it does not match 'ECR' at all?

Because this will give you what you want, will it not?

select regexp_replace('CR-123344','(.*)-','ECR-') 
from dual;